# Solutions based on augmented matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find the set of values of a for which the system of equations below has a unique solution.

$$x-2y-2z=-7$$
$$2x+(a-9)y-10z=-11$$
$$3x-6y+2az=-29$$

I rewrote the equations in the augmented matrix form as:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-2&-2&-7\\
  2&(a-9)&-10&-11\\ 
  3&-6&2a&-29
\end{array}
\right] $$

And then used row reduction:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-2&-2&-7\\
  0&(a-5)&-6&3\\ 
  0&0&(2a+6)&-8
\end{array}
\right] $$

After this step however, I do not know how to come to the conclusion as to which values of a will give a unique solution.

I know $a\neq-3$ because then the last equation in the reduced form would be inconsistent, since $2(-3)+6\neq-8$.

Is my concept correct here?

The other answer is $a\neq5$ but I do not understand why this is so. Can somebody help me out please?

Note: This question is taken from a CIE A Level Past Paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your concept is correct. After row reduction your system becomes

$$x-2y-2z=-7$$
$$(a-5)y-6z=3$$
$$(2a+6)z=-8$$

If $2a+6=0$ or $a=-3$, then the last equation $\textbf{is not}$ satisfied for any $z,$ but we are looking for a unique solution. Thus $a\neq -3$ which gives $z=-\frac{4}{a+3}.$

Now have $z$ and substituting into the second equation and re-arranging gives

$$(a-5)y=3+6z=\frac{3(a-5)}{a+3}$$

Now if $a=5$ then the equation $\textbf{is}$ satisfied for any $y$ (since we will have $0=0$). However we want a unique solution. Hence $a\neq 5$, and we obtain that $$y=\frac{3}{a+3}$$

and finally substituting into the first equation gives

$$x=-\frac{7a+23}{a+3}$$

Thus for $a\neq -3$ and $a\neq 5$ we obtain the unique solution

$$(x,y,z)=\left(-\frac{7a+23}{a+3},\frac{3}{a+3},-\frac{4}{a+3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

When you write $2(-3)+6 \neq -8$ I think you are making a hidden mistake.
Your last equation is in fact $(2a+6) z = 8$, and the question we are asking here is if there is a value for $a$ when there can't exist a solution, and we can easily find such a case when $a = -3$.

If we simply ask the question looking at the last 2 rows; Is there an $a$ such that no value for $y$ and $z$ can satisfy the equations $(a-5)y -6z = -11$ and $(2a+6)z = 8$?
For a nice simple linear system like this, the only way for that to happen is if the right hand sides are linearly dependent.
It not also becomes clear that $a = 5$ will turn our system of equations to
$-6z = -11$ and $16z = 8$, which clearly has no solution.